# Is$[f(x)]^a_b:= \begin{cases} b, & \text{if }f(x)>b, \\ f(x), & \text{if }a\le f(x)\le b, \\ a, & \text{if }f(x)<a \end{cases}$measurable function?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Show that if the function $f(x)$ is measurable on a set E, then the function $[f(x)]^a_b$ defined by 
$$[f(x)]^a_b:=
\begin{cases}
b, & \text{if }f(x)>b, \\
f(x), & \text{if }a\le f(x)\le b, \\
a, & \text{if }f(x)<a
\end{cases}$$ is also measurable on E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\{x \in E: a \le f(x) \le b\}, B=\{x \in E: f(x)>b\}$ and $C=\{x \in E: f(x)<a\}$.

Since $f$ is measurable, the above sets are measurable.

We have

$[f(x)]^a_b=1_A f+1_B b+1_Ca$.

Can you procceed ?

Comment: I think I don't quite understand about that. so can you show the next process?. What can I do next?

Comment: The functions $1_A f,1_B b$ and $1_Ca$ are measurable !